# How to develop Blackberry application in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I created an application in Sencha Touch 2 and i gave it to Phonegap, it built APK but not blackberry OTA.

Can anyone give me solution to create Blackberry OTA install in Phonegap using Sencha Touch 2?

Answer (score 0):

Why APK? Did you use Android or Blackberry build?

[This link shows how to use PhoneGap with Blackberry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Blackberry)

PS: If you used BB build already, what's the error?

Comment: when i click ota intall in phonegap it open like a test file

Comment: please provided some screenshots and details to clarify your problem